# Password found in heap dump - iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, memory-dump

I created a small Cordova iOS hybrid project which has login functionality in JSP page. Just in curiosity, we took memory dump in Jailbroken device and checked for plain text password. Password is visible in memory heap dump. Is there any way to remove sensitive information from heap memory.

Note: I'm not storing password anywhere in native implementation. Even during native handling also, I only used NSData to process sensitive information and make the NSData to nil after processing.

Thanks.

Comment: Setting the reference to nil simply removes the reference. It does not overwrite the memory. Even if the object is released, the old value may be still sitting on the heap. You could try explicitly writing new data to the NSData once the operation is complete

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually my question is, Is there any way to clean up heap dump?

Comment: me too @Dax can your find solution for the same